# How can modify selected columns (given by a string vector) of data frame

Tags: r, data.table

I am new to R. I have a dataframe (from data.table called DT_All) and I need to normalize data in all columns except column names given in a string vector.

When I access column by indices it works. When I tried to access data by column names it doesn't work.

Say I want to normalize data in all columns by a column called "Awake" except following listed columns. Their column indices are 1:8 and the last column of dataframe. After exclusion, the rest of the columns are numeric.

```
# find variable names for normalization. Keep the variables except ones listed below
excldVarNms=setdiff(names(dt_All),c("SubjectID","Date","Day","Weekend","WorkDay","LeisureDay","DayStart","DayStop","Domain"));

#this line works - normalize dataframe by "Awake" time
dt_All[,9:(ncol(dt_All)-1)]=(dt_All[,9:(ncol(dt_All)-1)]/dt_All$Awake)*480

#this expression doesn't work
dt_All[,excldVarNms,with=FALSE]=(dt_All[,excldVarNms,with=FALSE]/dt_All$Awake)*480
```

> Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , plotVarNms, with = FALSE, value
> = list( :
> unused argument (with = FALSE)

```
#this also fails obviously because data.table thinks excldVarNms is a column name
dt_All[,excldVarNms]=(dt_All[,excldVarNms]/dt_All$Awake)*480
```

> Error in `[.data.table`(dt_All, , excldVarNms) :
> j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'excldVarNms' is not found.

Any thoughts on what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

Sample data:

```r
samp <- setDT(structure(list(group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), ignore = c(3, 7, 4, 2, 10, 6, 8, 1, 5, 9), V1 = c(3, 10, 2, 1, 8, 4, 7, 5, 9, 6), V2 = c(3, 7, 9, 6, 4, 8, 2, 5, 10, 1), V3 = c(8, 4, 10, 9, 5, 6, 7, 2, 1, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
samp
#      group ignore    V1    V2    V3
#     <char>  <num> <num> <num> <num>
#  1:      A      3     3     3     8
#  2:      A      7    10     7     4
#  3:      A      4     2     9    10
#  4:      A      2     1     6     9
#  5:      A     10     8     4     5
#  6:      A      6     4     8     6
#  7:      B      8     7     2     7
#  8:      B      1     5     5     2
#  9:      B      5     9    10     1
# 10:      B      9     6     1     3
```

Scaling (normalizing) per group with a set of columns. In this method,

```r
samp[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(z) as.numeric(scale(z))), by = .(group), .SDcols = cols]
samp
#      group ignore         V1          V2          V3
#     <char>  <num>      <num>       <num>       <num>
#  1:      A      3 -0.4682929 -1.36694185  0.42257713
#  2:      A      7  1.4985373  0.35972154 -1.26773138
#  3:      A      4 -0.7492686  1.22305323  1.26773138
#  4:      A      2 -1.0302444 -0.07194431  0.84515425
#  5:      A     10  0.9365858 -0.93527600 -0.84515425
#  6:      A      6 -0.1873172  0.79138739 -0.42257713
#  7:      B      8  0.1463850 -0.61858957  1.42587956
#  8:      B      1 -1.0246951  0.12371791 -0.47529319
#  9:      B      5  1.3174651  1.36089706 -0.85552774
# 10:      B      9 -0.4391550 -0.86602540 -0.09505864
```

(N.B.: I would prefer to have been able to use `lapply(.SD, scale)`, but since `scale` assigns a class to its return value, `data.table` gets confused and will error; wrapping that with `as.numeric` removes the class and it operates as it should. You may not need to do this with your own normalization, depending on how it is implemented.)

It would be nice to be able to use `patterns(.)` or similar for `.SDcols`; the only problem with that is that reassignment of those dynamic columns is not as clear (see [data.table#4163](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4163) for the fix that would work as `samp[, names(.SD) := lapply(.SD, function(z) as.numeric(scale(z))), .SDcols = patterns("^V")]`.)

Comment: Thanks. I am very new to R. Didn't realize I can change the data.table itself within [] and skip reassignment. But I still don't understand the reason why "dt_All[,excldVarNms,with=FALSE]=(dt_All[,excldVarNms,with=FALSE]/dt_All$Awake)*480" fails

Comment: I've never used `data.table` and tried to use `with=` on the LHS of an assignment: trying that defeats the referential semantics and efficiency of `data.table`. For similar reasons, likely, `.SDcols` doesn't work on the LHS of an external assignment. Perhaps using `with=` on the LHS *could* work somehow, but ... it is generally encouraged to use `data.table`-semantics here.